# onPreferenceClick not working in android

Tags: android

I have problem implementing Preference.
When i run my app and click on the preference tab nothing happens.
I don't know what is wrong with the code, Because logcat don't show anything.
And thanks in advance.

```
public class Reset extends PreferenceActivity{

private Preference myPreference;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myPreference = findPreference("reset");
    myPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
            Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Reset.this);
            alertDialog.setMessage("Reset?");
            alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    SharedPreferences settings =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());                          
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.clear();
                    editor.commit();
                } }); 
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                } }); 
            alertDialog.show();
            return false;
        }
    });

}

}
```

XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <Preference android:title="Reset Score" android:key="reset">
 </Preference>
 </PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: `myPreference` is not initialized, so it's always null and `NullPointerException` is thrown at `onCreate()` method.

Comment: I edited my code but same problem.

Comment: The problem is the same @Taha, `myPreference` is null and you're getting the preferenceManager from it. Use this instead: `myPreference = findPreference("reset");`

Comment: I did as you said but the problem still exist. And logcat don't show anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line to your code:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

This code is working:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class Reset extends PreferenceActivity{

private Preference myPreference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
myPreference = findPreference("reset");
myPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
        Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Reset.this);
        alertDialog.setMessage("Reset?");
        alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                SharedPreferences settings =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());                          
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.clear();
                editor.commit();
            } }); 
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            } }); 
        alertDialog.show();
        return false;
    }
});

}

}
```

And remember to add your activity: Reset to the Manifest:

Answer (score 1):

The key line you are missing is

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

Once you add that everything should work.

```
public class Reset extends PreferenceActivity {

    private Preference myPreference;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        myPreference = findPreference("reset");
        myPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
                Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Reset.this);
                alertDialog.setMessage("Reset?");
                alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.clear();
                        editor.commit();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: What isn't working about it, I can run this exact code in eclipse and get the AlertDialog.  What import do you have for the Builder class? It should be AlertDialog.Builder

Comment: Thanks i solved it. I put the code in New class with name Reset but it don't work . Then i transfer it to my preference class and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Use .equals instead of == to compare objects.

```
if (preference.equals(myPrefernce)){

...

}
```